Shiny generates duplicated outcome in print(Inspect(rules))
Using the apriori algorithm, print(rules) generates one rule, but when the command print(inspect(rules)) is executed, the one rule is duplicated in the output.
 rules1 <- apriori(df[4:12], 
                         control=list(verbose=F),
                         parameter = list(minlen=3, supp=0.005, conf = 0.2),
                         appearance = list(rhs=c("risktype=x1", "risktype=x2", "risktype=x3"),
                                           lhs =c(paste0("technology=", as.character(input$Lst7)), paste0("domain=", as.character(input$Lst8)))))
       
       # rules1ss <- subset(rules1, lhs %oin% c(paste0("technology=", as.character(input$Lst7)), paste0("domain=", as.character(input$Lst8))))

       
       rules.sorted <- sort(rules1, by ="lift")
       subset.matrix <- is.subset(rules.sorted, rules.sorted)
       redundant <- colSums(subset.matrix, na.rm = T ) > 1
       rules.pruned <- rules.sorted[!redundant]
       print(inspect(rules.pruned))

The output in shiny is showing as:


Remove the print().
inspect() already prints the rules to the screen and returns the rule invisibly. Your print call prints this returned rule, so you are basically printing the same rule twice.

yes. its working fine. i hve removed the print ()
